# error: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' while Compiling linphone-iphone

Tags: iphone, build, xcode8, linphone

I was trying to compile linphone-phone on Mac Sierra with Xcode 8.3.
 When I tried to compile the project I found this error

> /Users/apple/linphone-iphone/Classes/Utils/XMLRPCHelper.m:74:81:
>   Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter
>   of type 'const char *'

Please have a look at the detailed [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbQpX.png) of my project.

```
// LinphoneXmlRpcSession *requestSession = linphone_xml_rpc_session_new(LC, URL); // LinphoneXmlRpcRequest *request = 
linphone_xml_rpc_request_new(method.UTF8String, LinphoneXmlRpcArgString);
requestObject.xmlRpcRequest = linphone_xml_rpc_request_new(method.UTF8String, LinphoneXmlRpcArgString)
```

The last line produces the error

I have found [question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDrMWBwbTTAhWKHZQKHe7fCo8QFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19873562%2Fbeginner-c-incompatible-integer-to-pointer-conversion-passing-char-to-param&usg=AFQjCNHJdV_4QQVdyXi47hebrTZ6DXo6Gw&sig2=itoNJzopZhh_voOJWh6thw) like this but I did not find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: can you show an example of your code? you pretty much stated an obvious solution that you can't pass an int pointer into a character pointer. pointers don't convert automatically convert it to a char first

Comment: `//
 LinphoneXmlRpcSession *requestSession = linphone_xml_rpc_session_new(LC, URL);
 // LinphoneXmlRpcRequest *request = linphone_xml_rpc_request_new(method.UTF8String, LinphoneXmlRpcArgString);
  requestObject.xmlRpcRequest = linphone_xml_rpc_request_new(method.UTF8String, LinphoneXmlRpcArgString);`

you can see the detail in image I attached in the post.

Comment: Images of code are almost never helpful, since the reader cannot search/copy/paste/edit the code.  Please post an actual code sample.  You will want to include the header for the `lincode_xml_rpc_request_whatever_it_was` function too

Comment: sorry for the code arrangement. This is my very first post.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that `method.UTF8String` is a constant integer value that means "the UTF8 string type" instead of an actual UTF8 String.

Comment: Thanks@Tibrogargan.
Now what will be my solution?